# Formatting Timestamp Script - Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I have found a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291398/preventing-timestamp-formulas-from-recalculating-in-google-sheets) with a Google Sheets script that will be very beneficial for our team, but I am having trouble adjusting it for my needs. Ideally, the user will input an "X" in columns D,F,I,K,N and/or P, and the current time will display in the cell directly to the right. The timestamp should not update on sheet refreshes. Can anyone help? Here is the [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R2RV14BVcGhP5fVlP1sjE42fO_1YWY_31dtdO48HJqM/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far? Check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
if ( e.range.columnStart !== 4 && e.range.columnStart !== 6 
    && e.range.columnStart !== 9 && e.range.columnStart !== 11 
    && e.range.columnStart !== 14 && e.range.columnStart !== 16
    || e.value.toUpperCase() !== 'X') return;
e.range.offset(0, 1)
    .setValue(new Date());
}
```